# Perl string in Quote Word?

Tags: perl

Seem like my daily road block.  Is this possible?  String in qw?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter Your Number\n";
my $usercc = <>;

##split number
$usercc =~ s/(\w)(?=\w)/$1 /g;

print $usercc;

## string in qw, hmm..

my @ccnumber = qw($usercc);
```

I get Argument "$usercc" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you want to assign a list just do `my @ccnumber = ($usercc);`

Comment: Why `$usercc =~ s/(\w)(?=\w)/$1 /g;`? If that is what you actually wanted `my @ccnumber = split /(\w)\s*/ $usercc;` would work. I don't understand why you would want that though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**
From: http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/qw_function.html

> How it works
>
> `qw()` extracts words out of your string
>   using embedded whitsepace as the
>   delimiter and returns the words as a
>   list. Note that this happens at
>   compile time, which means that the
>   call to `qw()` is replaced with the list
>   before your code starts executing.

**Additionlly, no interpolation is possible in the string you pass to qw().**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of that, use

```
my @ccnumber = split /\s+/, $usercc;
```

Which does what you *probably* want, to split `$usercc` on whitespace.